# Is it possible to upload a file with malicious filename?

Tags: file, http, upload

Is it possible to send a http upload request a file to a Apache or IIS that will have a fileName with "../" or ".." that wouldn't be rejected and would be passed to php or ASP.Net engine?

Comment: Hardly think so, that would be disastrous! You could compromise the filesystem or the file table.

Answer (score 1):

Not really the way you are asking. By the time it gets to the server the browser has read the file and delivered it as a chunk of content with no information about where it came from other than the original file name which you can choose to use or discard.

Generally file uploads go into a temporary storage place (e.g. /tmp) and then need to be moved out of there to somewhere which you can control and name.

This storage is configured on the server, and so any attempt to put path info into the filename should also be blocked by the file upload implementation of the server which should sanitise the filenames again if the browser didn't already do so.

If there's a bug then all bets are off though.

Comment: But in temp dir it could be named anyway, like with guid, yet the http field would transport proposed file name and any scripting platform like php or asp.net would then try to save it with this name. So if someone passes this malicious filename, would that be caught by IIS or Apache?